# codepen geolocation doesn't work

Tags: javascript

In my snippet [here](https://codepen.io/jinlin917/pen/VbWVBO?editors=0012),
I am testing out the `navigator.geolocation` functionality. However, the web browser doesn't even prompt me to give location permission after it loads. Why is this?

Here is my code:

```
var x = $("#location");
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't call the getLocation function

Comment: That's because you aren't executing the functions, you're just defining them.
[https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdjqMX](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdjqMX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the jQuery's html() method instead of innerHTML.

```
var x = $("#location");
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, error);
  } else {
    x.html("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}
function showPosition(position) {
   console.log(position)
    x.html("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude); 
}
function error(err){
  console.log(err)
}  

getLocation();
```